# Drop down list validation angular

Tags: html, angular

Want to print *Required on submit if Dropdown value is not selected.

here is my html .

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory.id" formControlName="Category" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && Category.errors }">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{category.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && Category.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="Category.errors.required">Category is required</div>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"   >Add to Cart</button>
```

here is my ts file .

```
cart_form = new FormGroup({
    Category: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

  });
```

Comment: can you please edit code in answer?

Comment: MiguelPinto make it for me :). -well, I'll remove the (change) too-. To control a FormGroup or a FormControl Change is better aproach "subscribe" to valueChanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need change your html to:

```
 <form [formGroup]="cart_form" >

    <select formControlName="category" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
            <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of categories">{{item.name}}</option>
          </select> 
          <div *ngIf="!cart_form.controls.category.valid" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="cart_form.controls.category.errors.required">Title is required</div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" [disabled]="cart_form.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And your component to

```
categories = [ {id: 1, name : 'test1'}, {id: 2, name : 'test12'}];
      selectedCategory = null;

      cart_form = new FormGroup({
        category: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),

      });
```

i build a demo for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-ngmodel-pnm31t?file=app/app.module.ts

Comment: Form is still submitting when there is no value is selected

Comment: @MoxShah you can verify if form isvalid before submit values ou disable the button
if is invalid. I update my answer with disabled button

Comment: thanks @Miguel pinto, can you please tell me how to do a on submit validation,want to know for learning purpose.

Comment: @MoxShah what do you want validate? the form values? if you want validate the form you can validate if form.valid and then you have the form.errors